# Visualization for Microservice flow

Tags: workflow, visualization, microservices

I have an application made of multiple microservices. I would like to visualize it for newer developer to understand the flow chart.

In some previous experiences, I have seen people draw flowchart like this one below.

**Question: What is this kind of flow chart called?

Is there any software tool that can draw it?**

[flow chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSkgz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This diagram is called "Sequence Diagram". You can learn about its annotation at [IBM Rational site](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html)

You can use tools like [Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com) to draw it. They have a community version for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://www.planttext.com/ for creating the flowchart, You need to first understand the syntax for creating the flowchart.

Answer (score 1):

This diagram is called "sequence diagram". You can use https://www.zenuml.com for creating sequence diagram. It comes with a super-developer-friendly syntax and is real-time.

Disclaimer: I am the author :)

Comment: This is awesome!